# Trouble Enabling CORS on S3

Tags: canvas, amazon-s3, cors

I set up CORS on an S3 bucket like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Here's a screenshot of the AWS console: https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/341y0o1n1X2a0O1X2s38/Screen%20Shot%202012-10-09%20at%209.59.44%20PM.png?v=2478ad83

When I point my [color-thief](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief/blob/master/js/color-thief.js) javascript at an image hosted on the same domain, everything [works as expected](https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/0u2H3b441G3S0B343S3Z/openredis-color-selecto.png?v=d3722011), but when I point to an asset in my S3 bucket, regardless of whether I run my script from localhost, lvh.me (which points to 127.0.0.1), or from the real interwebs, I get errors like this in Chrome 22:

```
Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
```

and this in Firefox 15:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

Here's what the headers look like in the Google Chrome Network Inspector:

```
Request URL:https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets-zeke.heroku.com/addons-zeke.heroku.com/catalogs/58/original.png
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:s3.amazonaws.com
If-Modified-Since:Tue, 09 Oct 2012 22:52:57 GMT
If-None-Match:"6de1a52294934c5e288894b84100d99b"
Referer:http://localhost:5000/marketplace/addons/sendgrid/edit
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4

Response Headers
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
x-amz-id-2: qGvoGlvpKeSSzelanWsIPDF3zd5wQzHTr27NZoUbhNqAM1QzmKcWHnTqIkKVxF/m
x-amz-request-id: FD24FB8CA244E327
Date: Wed, 10 Oct 2012 05:20:53 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Oct 2012 22:52:57 GMT
ETag: "6de1a52294934c5e288894b84100d99b"
Server: AmazonS3
```

And here's what the headers look like after I changed the URL structure to `{bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com` (and removed the period)
 from my bucket name.

```
Request URL:http://assets-zeke.s3.amazonaws.com/addons-zeke.heroku.com/catalogs/58/original.png
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:assets-zeke.s3.amazonaws.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://lvh.me:5000/marketplace/addons/airbrake/edit
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:6696
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Wed, 10 Oct 2012 17:56:17 GMT
ETag:"6de1a52294934c5e288894b84100d99b"
Last-Modified:Wed, 10 Oct 2012 17:50:38 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2:UGVKQ9VQbJ82DLDxR53uDP0ZUMgla+e0GU5vO9yLr6MsY8wijl9KnM7fOyDlT+ta
x-amz-request-id:8A16CF1E02A0106C
```

Shouldn't I be seeing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` here? Does the 304 mean that Amazon is caching the response?

Comment: Found a solution to this? I'm running into the same problem. Would really appreciate if you'd update with an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Request URL:https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets-zeke.heroku.com/addons-zeke.heroku.com/catalogs/58/original.png

Well, there's your problem. Because of the way that CORS and other cross-domain things work, you need to use *DNS-style addressing* to access your buckets.

Assuming your original URL is correct (it doesn't look like it, but I could totally be wrong), you'd want to use this URL instead:

```
http://assets-zeke.heroku.com.s3.amazonaws.com/addons-zeke.heroku.com/catalogs/58/original.png
```

In other words:

```
http://{bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/path/object.ext
```

Check out: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html for more explanation.

Comment: Good point. I changed the URL scheme to `{bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com` (and took the period (.) out of my bucket name, but I'm still not seeing those headers. I added the new headers to my question.

Comment: @Zeke. Did you get to the bottom of the problem? I'm having similar issues.

Comment: @Mike I ended up writing a blog post about my findings at http://zeke.heroku.com/blog/2012/10/11/s3-cors-canvas/. Thanks for reminding me to post the link here.

Comment: your blog doesn't load for me. Can you post something here to your question?

Comment: Sorry, my blog died but the source content lives on in this github repo: https://github.com/zeke/zeke.heroku.com/blob/master/source/_posts/2012-10-11-s3-cors-canvas.markdown

Comment: As mentioned in the blog post, it was important for me to also create the images in JS and set the "crossOrigin" property on them. (Using images from the DOM loaded from the other domain did not work.) Thanks Zeke!

Answer (score 9):

This can be caused by not having [enabled CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CORS_Enabled_Image) in your image element before it has loaded:

```
imgEl.crossOrigin = '';
```